# How much ram an app gets in windows phone 8.1 and can we extend it?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to find the limit of my app's ram so that i can design my app properly.

Earlier in windows phone 8 there was a class named DeviceStatus which could provide me with this result but in windows phone 8.1 that class has been removed. So could anyone provide me with an alternative of this class for windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 2):

The new class you're looking for is [Windows.System.MemoryManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx); in particular, the [AppMemoryUsageLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit.aspx) property.

This value can vary based on the amount of RAM the device has, and whether or not the process is a background task.

- For **512MB** RAM devices, the limit is **185MB**.
- For **1GB** RAM devices, the limit is **390MB**.
- For **2GB** RAM devices, the limit is **825MB**.

You can't extend the memory limit.